# keep text on the right side of an arrow

Tags: formatting, arrows, tikz-arrows

I draw an arrow and want to write text afterwards over multiple lines. Important is, that the text won't start on the left side of the new line below the arrow, but behind the arrow, where the first line started as well.

This is how it looks currently:

```
\tikz\draw[-Latex,line width=3pt] (0,0) -- (2,0);
Design of a decision framework as an extensive-form game
```

The problem is, that the last word "game" is printed below the arrow, but should be below the word "Design".

Comment: It's not very clear to me. Could you post a sketch of what you 'd like to have?

Comment: Is this one occurrence? Or are you expecting to have multiple instances of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the command `\tikz`, I suppose this is going to appear inside of the regular document, along with other text. In that case, I don't think you need Tikz for everything. You can use a simple list and change the bullet with the arrow you created.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mrarrow{%
    \tikz[yshift=.5\baselineskip]{\draw[-latex,line width=3pt] (0,0) -- (2,0);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\mrarrow}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam aliquet lorem nec turpis auctor placerat. In at nisi massa. Morbi commodo scelerisque mauris ut ultricies. Suspendisse quis ante neque. Mauris placerat tincidunt rutrum. Fusce vulputate nulla nibh, ac ullamcorper augue ornare id. Quisque lobortis rutrum tellus, tempus egestas felis consectetur at.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->,>=stealth',ultra thick] (0,0)--(2,0)node[pos=1,right]   {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam aliquet lorem nec \\turpis auctor placerat. In at nisi massa. Morbi commodo scelerisque mauris ut ultricies.\\ Suspendisse quis ante neque. Mauris placerat tincidunt rutrum. Fusce vulputate nulla \\nibh, ac ullamcorper augue ornare id. Quisque lobortis rutrum tellus, tempus egestas felis\\ consectetur at
        \end{tabular}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the tabular to do that, just set a `text width` in the node